# Include source file for maven build

Tags: java, maven

I have class SelfContainedRestServer.java that I need to build with help of maven. I do build  with `mvn clean install` command.

I get rest-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar file that does not contains any class files.
Maven build log show that no source files was included

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------------< com.example:rest-server >-----------------------
[INFO] Building rest-server 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ rest-server ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\java_test\mvn_selfcontained\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ rest-server ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\java_test\mvn_selfcontained\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ rest-server ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ rest-server ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\java_test\mvn_selfcontained\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ rest-server ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ rest-server ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.2.0:jar (default-jar) @ rest-server ---
[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
[INFO] Building jar: C:\java_test\mvn_selfcontained\target\rest-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ rest-server ---
[INFO] Installing C:\java_test\mvn_selfcontained\target\rest-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\g\.m2\repository\com\example\rest-server\1.0-SNAPSHOT\rest-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\java_test\mvn_selfcontained\pom.xml to C:\Users\g\.m2\repository\com\example\rest-server\1.0-SNAPSHOT\rest-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.234 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-10-17T12:21:22+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What I do wrong?

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Jersey Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.32</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.32</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jetty Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.44.v20210927</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.44.v20210927</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>SelfContainedRestServer</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

SelfContainedRestServer.java

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;
import org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer;

public class SelfContainedRestServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server server = new Server(8080); // You can choose any available port

        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.NO_SESSIONS);
        context.setContextPath("/");
        server.setHandler(context);

        ServletHolder jerseyServlet = context.addServlet(ServletContainer.class, "/api/*");
        jerseyServlet.setInitOrder(0);
        jerseyServlet.setInitParameter("jersey.config.server.provider.packages", "com.example");

        try {
            server.start();
            server.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            server.destroy();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check (or describe us) the [directory layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).